# How to collapse state chart UML in jointjs?

Tags: javascript, uml, visualization, jointjs, flowchart

I am new to jointjs and want to collapse the state diagram on click on a state. How should I do so?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to handle the event and hide/resize/transform the element

Comment: can you please explain with an example?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for me to edit? I don't know how your code looks like. In essence you have to listen for events, add a field that says collapsed: true or false then use that to collapse in the click event handler for that shape.